# How to fix image urls when processing css files with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

This is a Gulp task that I've set up. It concatenates, minifies andrenames a bunch of css files.

gulp.task('process-css', function() {

```
var files = [
    'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/bootstrap.css',
    'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/custom.css',
    'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/responsive.css',
    'themes/rubbish_taxi/css/jquery.fancybox.css'
];

return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat("main.css"))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.basename += ".min";
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('sourcemaps/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/my_theme/css/dist/'));
```

});

The problem is that there are hard-coded img urls in the source files (present in `css/`) so when I process these files and then output them in a subdirectory (`css/dist/`), the urls are broken and images do not display on the site (404 returned).

How can I make Gulp rewrite the img urls in the output file in order to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know the answer but one thing I would try is using a Sass or Less processor as your concatenator/minifier — I think both of them accept vanilla CSS as valid input and are likely to have this as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plugin such as **gulp-replace** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to replace arbitrary strings in any given files, it should do the trick in your case ;)

Comment: There are much better alternatives.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-url-adjuster or https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-rebase-urls.  Both designed precisely to fix the relative url problem in css after gulp processing.